# What is used to do this effect in webpage/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I found this website: http://www.vazco.eu/
What is used to do the animation (http://cl.ly/image/41100r2F401N)
 behind "Our Latest Projects" with dots and line - is not the only place where I see this but since now no idea how to achieve something similar!

can be done with pure javascript or with any js framework? can some one point me in the right direction please!

I don't know how to ask/explain better ...

Thank you and please forgive my bad english!

Comment: I can remember a demo **[here](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_lines)** that's similar

Comment: If you do a view source, it is an svg element.

Comment: threejs use  webgl -maybe I'm wrong - but I guess the similar effect achieved with threejs is done via webgl! also seem that OQX answer is the solution to my question - for this special case. For some complex example maybe threejs is the answer ... thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this site he is using SVG and for the drawing effect with time, you can use framework like [vivus](http://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email)

Comment: agree ..seem that svg animation do this kind of magic - thank you so much!

Comment: @OQX how did you know about vivus?

Comment: @caramba it was mentioned on HTML5 Weekly newsletter this week, I tinkered with it a little bit, it seems that it'll come in-handy someday :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Subscribed!! :)